# How to pass read-host input before being prompted?

Tags: powershell

suppose i have this cmdlet

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeOne,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeAll,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$View
)
```

now i have some conditional statements as follows:

```
if ($ChangeOne)
{
    $input = (Read-Host -prompt "Database")

    if (!$input) 
    { 
        Write-Host "`r`n`You MUST enter a DB Name! 1 more try...`r`n" -foregroundcolor cyan -backgroundcolor black

        $input = (Read-Host -prompt "Database")

        if (!$input) 
        { 
            Write-Host "`r`nNo DB Name entered...exiting script`r`n" -foregroundcolor magenta -backgroundcolor black    
            Write-host "----------------------------END of Script------------------------------"
            exit 1
        }
    }
}
```

This works great except now I am trying to call this script using WinRM from TFS, and TFS will not be interactive with Read-Host...instead, it would accept only direct arguments such as :

> script1.ps1 -ChangeOne databaseinput1

my question is, how can i allow Read-Host to be inputted on the command line without getting prompted? I am just trying to think of a way that TFS will accept read-host predefined input

i would think of something like this, but this wont work because `param` mandates it has to be at the top of the script...

```
if ($ChangeOne)
{
    param([string]$input)

    if (!$input) 
    { 
        Write-Host "`r`n`You MUST enter a DB Name! 1 more try...`r`n" -foregroundcolor cyan -backgroundcolor black

        $input = param([string]$input)

        if (!$input) 
        { 
            Write-Host "`r`nNo DB Name entered...exiting script`r`n" -foregroundcolor magenta -backgroundcolor black    
            Write-host "----------------------------END of Script------------------------------"
            exit 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Dynamic Parameters to check if the `-ChangeOne` switch is present and if so allow a `-DatabaseInput` parameter. I'm not sure if that's the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: @Jacob yes thats kinda what im looking for except i wasnt sure how to include it in the cmdlet binding. can you post a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Parameter Sets and Validation.

It would look something like this:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
Param(


    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$ChangeAll,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$View,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$ChangeOne,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
    [string]$Database = ${if ($ChangeOne)`{Read-Host -Prompt "Database"`} else `{""`}}
)
```

Alternately, if you know the scripts you're expecting to see, the validation can look like this:

```
[ValidateSet("Database1","Database2","Database3")]
```

The validation will handle making sure the input is acceptable, the switch will drive the requirement of the database parameter, and if you try to pass the database parameter without the -ChangeOne flag, it will also cause the script to abort with an error.

Comment: wouldnt this be contradictory?  mandatory = false then second one is true?   [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$ChangeOne,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]

Comment: also Read-Host -Prompt "Database"` ....Database seems predefined here. i want to allow the user to pass anything

Comment: The switch is not mandatory, That lets you not set it if you're passing other switches.  The database parameter is mandatory, but that is only enforced if the switch is set.

Comment: i see, thnx. what about Read-Host -Prompt "Database"` ....Database seems predefined here. i want to allow the user to pass anything

Comment: As far as the Database, that's why I shared two different validation solutions, one is just checking for null or empty, the other (optional) lets you define specific databases that are acceptable.

Comment: wait so you mean     [ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
    [string]$Database thats all i need?

Comment: Yes, if you want to just require it at the beginning.  you can set the Database parameter with a default value of Read-Host in the parameters.  When you do that, if a value is not passed, it will *then* try to apply the default value, which in this case, is code to prompt for input (which will still be validated)

Comment: i see. what if i want to validate another argument thats mandatory is also passed, i.e. $server? for exqample the command would look like this eventually: script1.ps1 -ChangeOne databaseinput1 server.domain.com

Comment: Each parameter validation is set up individually, it's optional decoration. This link should help you get started: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6)

Comment: oh i see so i would have another one like this:     [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
    [string]$Server = ${if ($ChangeOne)`{Read-Host -Prompt "Server"`} else `{""`}}

Comment: if it is always required, it would be easier to just pass `[string]$Database = (Read-Host -Prompt "Database")`  The rest of that was just to isolate the Read-Host command and only execute it if the ChangeOne flag is set.  If the value is always required, it's a lot simpler. (with the parameter and validationscript decoration as well)

Comment: yes its required but i wnat to be able to pass these required arguments like this directly on the commandline, so that i DONT get prompted: script1.ps1 -ChangeOne databaseinput1 server1

Comment: also its only required for ChangeOne

Comment: In that case, yes, my hacky magic is required for the Read-Host default value.  If I come up with a better way to do that, I'll update my solution.

Comment: question if two params are required, cant i just do it like this:     [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
    [string]$Database = ${if ($ChangeOne)`{Read-Host -Prompt "Database"`} else `{""`}},     [string]$Server = ${if ($ChangeOne)`{Read-Host -Prompt "Server"`} else `{""`}},

Comment: No, you'll need to do the parameter and validation decoration for each parameter individually.

Comment: ok lets say i want to use $Database for another switch set as well, let say ChangeAll. i defined the parameter and validation decoration for itindividually for it but it says Duplicate parameter $Database in parameter list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193496/discussion-between-cataster-and-ryan).

Answer (score 1):

To add `DynamicParam` you need to build the object step by step. I use the below template to create mine, The main bits to note are `$ParameterName`, `[String]` which you can change as needed.

```
function MyFunction
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
        [Switch]$ChangeOne,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$true)]
        [Switch]$ChangeAll,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
        [Switch]$View
    )

    DynamicParam
    {
        if($ChangeOne)
        {
            #OutputObject
            $ParameterName = 'DatabaseInput'
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)
            $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
            return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to validate the input against some predefined values, you can create an array (which can be hardcoded, or dynamically generated).

Note that the following lines were added

```
 $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidationArray)
 $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
```

and

```
$ValidationArray = 1..9
```

The complete `DynamicParam` block is below

```
   DynamicParam
    {
        if($ChangeOne)
        {
            #Array of values to validate against
            $ValidationArray = 1..9

            #OutputObject
            $ParameterName = 'DatabaseInput'
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)
            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidationArray)
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
            $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
            return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
        }
    }
```

These are the two templates that I re-use. Test it out in PowerShell ISE with intellisense.

These 'templates' could probably be cleaned up a bit, so there may be better examples out there.

**Edit**

You can manually specify positions for the arguments, we need to set the position attribute on our parameter with `$ParameterAttribute.Position = 1`. I have also set the position to `0` on our switches, I would suggest manually setting the position of all the parameters for peace of mind.

I also neglected to mention previously that you need to access the values via `$PsBoundParameters`. In this example I have assigned them to variables in the `begin` block. This makes them easier to reference throughout the function, but you can just use `$PsBoundParameters["DatabaseInput"]`.

```
function MyFunction
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View',PositionalBinding=$false)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [Switch]$ChangeOne,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [Switch]$ChangeAll,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false, Position=0)]
        [Switch]$View
    )

    DynamicParam
    {
        if($ChangeOne)
        {
            #Array of values to validate against
            $ValidationArray = 1..9

            #OutputObject
            $ParameterName = 'DatabaseInput'
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $ParameterAttribute.Position = 1
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)


            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidationArray)
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

            $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
            return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
        }
    }

    begin
    {
        $ChangeOne = $PsBoundParameters["ChangeOne"]
        $ChangeAll = $PsBoundParameters["ChangeAll"]
        $View = $PsBoundParameters["ChangeAll"]
        $DatabaseInput = $PsBoundParameters["DatabaseInput"]
    }

    process
    {
        if($databaseInput)
        {
            return $databaseInput
        }
        else
        {
            return $False
        }
    }
}
```

So running:

```
MyFunction -ChangeAll
MyFunction -ChangeOne -DatabaseInput 3
MyFunction -ChangeOne 6
```

Gives:

```
False
3
6
```

**Edit 2**

To create more parameters, you need to add more objects to the `$RuntimeParameterDictionary`

```
function MyFunction
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View',PositionalBinding=$false)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [Switch]$ChangeOne,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [Switch]$ChangeAll,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false, Position=0)]
        [Switch]$View
    )

    DynamicParam
    {
        if($ChangeOne)
        {


            #Create a dictionary of parameters
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

            ####Parameter 1
            $ParameterName = "databaseInput"

            #Array of values to validate against
            $ValidationArray = 1..9

            #Create parameter attributes
            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $ParameterAttribute.Position = 1
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

            #Add validation (omit if not needed)
            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidationArray)
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

            #Create the parameter
            $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)

            #Add the parameter to the dictionary
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)

            ###Parameter 2
            $ParameterName = "Server"

            #Array of values to validate against
            $ValidationArray = "One","Two","Three"

            #Create parameter attributes
            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $ParameterAttribute.Position = 2
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

            #Add validation (omit if not needed)
            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidationArray)
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

            #Create the parameter
            $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)

            #Add the parameter to the dictionary
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)

            #Return parameters
            Return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
        }
    }

    begin
    {
        $ChangeOne = $PsBoundParameters["ChangeOne"]
        $ChangeAll = $PsBoundParameters["ChangeAll"]
        $View = $PsBoundParameters["ChangeAll"]
        $DatabaseInput = $PsBoundParameters["DatabaseInput"]
        $Server = $PsBoundParameters["Server"]
    }

    process
    {
        if($databaseInput)
        {
            Return $DatabaseInput,$Server
        }
        else
        {
            Return $False
        }
    }
}
```

So, running the following:

```
MyFunction -ChangeOne -databaseInput 3 -Server Two
MyFunction -ChangeOne 7 Two
```

Returns:

```
3
Two
7
Two
```

References: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2017/09/01/scripting-tips-tricks-dynamic-parameters/

Comment: what if i want to allow input? instead of $ParameterName = 'DatabaseInput' i want something like $ParameterName = 'arg[1]'. my original goal is something like this: script1.ps1 -ChangeOne databaseinput1

Comment: I have updated the answer, to demonstrate positional parameters and also how to bind the parameter values. Hope that's what you're after :). I don't have any experience running scripts in this manner `script1.ps1 -ChangeOne databaseinput1`, so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll take a look.

Comment: ok i think the edit is what im looking for, but i have a question: wat if i have another parameter mandatory to be passed besides databaseinput? lets say i wnat both database input followed by the server

Comment: nope doesnt work...Unexpected token '$DatabaseInput' in expression or statement

Comment: I've updated the answer to show more than one parameter, The examples posted work for me in PowerShell ISE - Are you sure it's exact?

Comment: i am running it like this (my ultimate goal): script1.ps1 -ChangeOne 7 Two

Comment: ok i put your code in a new script. i removed My function and just copied the portions inside. it works script1.ps1 -ChangeOne 7 Two. however, when i get rid of begin/process, i get these errors: Unexpected token '$ChangeOne' in expression or statement....i thought they are not necessary...